# How do I get rid of this Joomla! page header?

Tags: php, html, joomla, header, content-management-system

I'm new to Joomla, and I'm trying to create my portfolio on it. My issue right now is that I've hidden every header, detail, tag, etc under articles in Joomla, and somehow this header still shows:
http://imgur.com/12o5t2I

How do I get rid of this header through Joomla? Should I just hide it via CSS instead? I know I can just make it disappear in CSS, but I'm trying to learn how Joomla works so I'm able to work with it in future projects. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of Joomla page header.

> 1. Click on the “Menus” menu and select “Main Menu”.
> 2. Click on the menu item that represents your home page (usually
>      “Home” or something similar)
> 3. On the right side, click on “Page Display Options”
> 4. Set “Show Page Heading” to “No”
> 5. Click on “Save

Work for me, Regards. :)